# how to refresh compiled views?

Tags: laravel-4

I have uploaded my app to MS Azure, of course, it runs fine locally, however, at cloud, I get error in file:

```
D:\home\site\wwwroot\app\storage\views\0854091fefacaa8cd8bcf9d5064fb8ec
```

which is in `default.blade.php` ,although I have fixed the error, I still get the old version of `0854091fefacaa8cd8bcf9d5064fb8ec`

How to force laravel generate a new compiled view? 
Also, is it called compiled view? or what's the right name for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's called a compiled view. You can just delete the file, or simply all files in the directory. This will cause Laravel to recompile them for your next request.

---

If you're on a linux terminal, just run this to clear the directory:

```
rm /path/to/laravel/app/storage/views/*
```

Comment: aha! its that simple :)

Comment: won't "php artisan dump-autoload" simply recompile the views?

Comment: @Th3Alchemist No autoloading has nothing to do with compiling views